# SCOM - Issue with single server domain-management & agent

Tags: windows, server, scom

for my new task I have to use SCOM to monitoring non-domain server/computer. My company told me to do it with only 1 server management that contains others SCOM features. So I have a server Windows 2016 with SCOM with a local domain, and I have to connect the others devices. It seems easy, but I have a problem with certificates: when I try to certificates my server & computers, and I'll import the certificate with MOMCertImport, in Event Viewer I see the event id 21007, that tell me "*The OpsMgr Connector cannot create a mutually authenticated connection to 'PC-NAME' because it is not in a trusted domain.*" So I have the certificates installed but I can't anyway connect Agent to SCOM, What will I do? I search anywhere for this problem, but any solution not work with me!

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to look at.

1. The certificate: must have both client auth and server auth purposes.
2. Authentication is MUTUAL, i.e. you agent confirms its identity to a gateway, or to a management server, AND the gateway or management server confirms its identity to the agent.
3. Certificates must be issued to EXACT conputer FQDN. If you rename, or join domain, or change DNS suffix => this will invalidate certificate, because FQDN changes.
4. Install and bind certificates at both participating servers (i.e. agent and (MS or GW)). This is because #2.
5. Obviously, you need individual certificates for each server, because of #3.
6. Ensure, that both servers can maintain trust chanin to own certificate and to other party's one. Ideally, if you have a single root/issuing CA, which used to issue both certificates. In this case, just install root/issuing CA certs in appropriate storages in local computer account. If using self-signed, you need to install them as trusted at other party.

Comment: When I'll re-take the project, I'll give you a feedback about this process
Thanks

Comment: I have root CA in both servers, but nothing is changed

Comment: yor PKI has just one CA, which is both issuing and root? i.e. no intermediate CAs? So, the root cert should be in Trusted Root Certification Authorites, and any intermediate ones are in Intermediate Certification Authorities. When you open each machines certs -- are thsy shown as trusted with no issues?

Comment: Well. Assume that both the management server (or gateway) and the client have this certificate bound using momcertutil (be CAREFUL -- it may break connection to othe components, so better have a gatway in the middle), and then health service was restarted at both sides to apply cert binding.